# Is "FLUSH TABLES, PRIVILEGES;" the same as "FLUSH TABLES; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, does executing `FLUSH TABLES, PRIVILEGES;` have the same effect as executing `FLUSH TABLES;` and then executing `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`? Also, would this hold true of any flush options (`FLUSH LOGS;` etc.)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/flush.html

Syntax is

```
FLUSH [NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG | LOCAL] flush_option [, flush_option] ...
```

Which means upon executing the command `FLUSH TABLES, PRIVILEGES;` it will flush all tables followed by privileges.

Yes should be same as

```
FLUSH Tables; 
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```